# How can I use existing MD files with Docusaurus?

Tags: markdown, documentation, docusaurus

We already have a significant amount of documentation in the form of `README.md` files throughout our project as well as other markdown files. We are looking to use Docusaurus for more advanced functionality such as search and navigation. How can we best incorporate the existing documentation into a docusaurus site?